# Does string_agg() of Postgres cause low performance? If it is, how can I improve it?

Tags: postgresql

I have created a view which collects names in separate column from its mapping tables.

When I am joining with my main table, query is taking more time. I hope it is happening because of string_agg() which contains DISTINCT.

Is my assumption correct?
If it can cause low performance, is there a way to rectify it.

Sample Code:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW .training_catalog_mapped_data
    AS SELECT t.catalog_id,
        string_agg(DISTINCT a.audiences_name::text, ','::text ORDER BY (a.audiences_name::text)) AS audiences,
        string_agg(DISTINCT k.keywords_name::text, ','::text ORDER BY (k.keywords_name::text)) AS keywords,
        string_agg(DISTINCT l.location_name::text, ','::text ORDER BY (l.location_name::text)) AS locations,
        string_agg(DISTINCT pub.publish_to_name::text, ','::text ORDER BY (pub.publish_to_name::text)) AS publish_to,
        string_agg(DISTINCT top.topic_name::text, ','::text ORDER BY (top.topic_name::text)) AS topics
       FROM lat_oct_29.training_catalog t
         LEFT JOIN mapping_audiences_view a ON t.catalog_id = a.catalog_id //--> This is a view
         LEFT JOIN mapping_keywords_view k ON t.catalog_id = k.catalog_id   //--> This is a view
         LEFT JOIN mapping_location_view l ON t.catalog_id = l.catalog_id //--> This is a view
         LEFT JOIN mapping_publish_to_view pub ON t.catalog_id = pub.catalog_id  //--> This is a view
         LEFT JOIN mapping_topic_view top ON t.catalog_id = top.catalog_id  //--> This is a view
      GROUP BY t.catalog_id;
```

Comment: It's probably the `DISTINCT` and not the `string_agg` that harms performance, but for a definitive answer please add `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe `DISTINCT` and multiple different `ORDER BY` clauses.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexes) and the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** (not just a "simple" explain). [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) or upload the plan to https://explain.depesz.com